# Moving an OEM partition (on Windows 10) to the end of the disk

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I'm planning to use gparted to move a(the?) OEM partition created by Windows 10 to the end of the disk. The disk looks like:

[image: win 10 disk partitions]

Can the OEM partition be safely moved to the end of the disk?

I tried it earlier with gparted and there were gaps of unallocated space in between the OS (C:) partition and the newly moved free partition at the end. Can these spaces be used so that the OS partition is contiguous up until the start of the OEM partition?

Comment: The partition in question isn’t even required.  It doesn’t normally exist if you were to install Windows from an standard ISO.

Comment: So, should it be safe to remove/overwrite/use that space as part of OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually delete and do everything using diskpart.exe via your CMD:

- Launch cmd.exe as administrator (right-click "Launch as administrator")
- Type `diskpart.exe` (then <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Type: `list disk` then `select disk <id_of_your_disk>`
- Then `list volume` or `list partition` and `select volume(or partition) <id_of_your_volume_or_partition>`
- Now you can do anything; type `help` if you need some help
- **IF YOUR PARTITON OR VOLUME IS PROTECTED:** : ex to delete selected partition `delete partition override` , but be sure it's    backed up